# Integral elements over an ideal in an integrally closed domain and the minimal polynomial over the field of fractions

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, integral-extensions

Proposition 5.15 of Atiyah-Macdonald (Commutative Algebra) says that if $A\subset B$ are integral domains, $A$ integrally closed, $I$ an ideal of $A$, and $x\in B$ is integral over $I$, then the coefficients of the minimal polynomial $f$ of $x$ over the field of fractions of $A$ are in $\sqrt{I}$.

Is there any kind of converse to this result? That is, is there a condition on $f$ that holds if and only if $x$ is integral over $I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 5.14 in A-M, if $A \subseteq B$, $I$ is an ideal  and $x \in B$, then $x$ is integral over $I$ iff $x$ is integral over $\sqrt{I}$.

Indeed, letting $C$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $B$, 5.14 tells you that the integral closure of $I$ in $B$ is $\sqrt{IC}$, and the integral closure of $\sqrt{I}$ in $B$ is $\sqrt{(\sqrt{I}C)}$.  It is trivial to check that these are the same.

Therefore the converse of 5.15 is also true.

Comment: Note that the A-M definition of integral is non-standard.  Usually integral refers to the existence of a relation $x^{n} + \sum_{i=i}^{n} a_i x^{n- i} =0$ with $a_i \in I^i$

Comment: Oh really? Where for example?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could look at anything written by Northcott, Rees, Eisenbud, Huneke, Swanson, Hochster, Vasconcelos... and I'm sure any other author I could think of who has written about integral closure of ideals.  I'm not sure why A-M defines it this way other than to state 5.15